# Как загрузить сайт сделанный на yii2 на хостинг. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, phpmyadmin

Ознакомился с фреймворком yii2 и сейчас первый раз переношу сайт http://pixargrid.com/ с локального хостинга на реальный. Выгрузил все файлы в паку public_html.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все отлично работает на главной странице по директории http://pixargrid.com/, а при переходе на другие страницы (http://pixargrid.com/views/site/login.php - пример) выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут я зашел в консоль разработчика во вкладку network и мне выдало что файл не найден хоть файловая директория верна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так и правильно ли я все делаю, в фалах .htaccess вот такое содержимое:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: откройте логи и посмотрите

Comment: как их можно открыть? Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, никогда этим не занимался.

Comment: возможно разные версии программного обеспечения на локалке и сервере